# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type RasterizeStringAlgorithm has been deleted

Tags: qgis, plugins, c

There is a very similar problem to mine, but with a different plugin. The error is the same.

The error is this:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type RasterizeStringAlgorithm has been deleted

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/belli/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rasterizestring\rasterize_string_provider.py", line 60, in loadAlgorithms
    self.addAlgorithm( alg )
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type RasterizeStringAlgorithm has been deleted

Versão do Python: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
Versão do QGIS: 3.10.11-A Coruña A Coruña, d2171173e4.
```

I am not an expert in programming language (IT).

Comment: Kindly add a link to the duplicate question, so that others can also know.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `rasterize_string_provider.py` file stated in the error
- Go to line 60
- Remove for loop (two lines)

  ```
  for alg in self.alglist:
      self.addAlgorithm(alg)
  ```
- Add the following lines

  ```
  self.addAlgorithm(RasterizeStringAlgorithm())
  self.addAlgorithm(GenerateIntegerFieldEditAlgorithm())
  self.addAlgorithm(GenerateIntegerFieldCreationAlgorithm())
  ```
- Save file and restart QGIS.